# Can I integrate a file not in my client spec?

Tags: version-control, perforce, perforce-client-spec, perforce-branch-spec, perforce-integrate

Is there a way to integrate files not in your client spec?

Specifically we've got a directory that contains a large number of static libraries that I build locally (so I don't need them out of source control), and would prefer not to have to pull them down from the server just to do an integrate.

In branch spec:

//project1/project/lib/... //project2/project/external/project1/lib/...

In my client spec:

-//project1/project/lib/... //cleintspec/project1/project/lib/...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not clear from your question of direction of integration is an issue. But you can integrate from files not in your client spec, but never *to* files.

An alternative would be to use a branch spec that misses off the library folder mapping. Just copy the current branch spec, and filter that out. Then you can integrate quite happily and the libs will be ignored.